Join tables selecting all rows from one and unmatched rows from other
I have a table UPPER



ID
Value




1
A


2
B


3
C


4
D



and a table LOWER



ID
Value




1
c


2
d



LOWER is a subest of UPPER.  I want to join UPPER and LOWER to select all rows from LOWER and unmatched rows from UPPER, the result should be



ID
Value




1
A


2
B


3
c


4
d



Whats a query to achieve this?

Search for LEFT JOIN for examples

It's not as simple as a left join, because it's a sub set,  the values column needs to be populated with values from both. Not just selecting upper.value and lower.value

What RDBMS do you use?

Is it a mistake that in your result, c and d are written in lower case? Shouldn't they be in upper case? If they should be in lower case, please explain why.

Is it not:
select 
     u.id
   , coalesce(l.value, u.value) as value
from upper u
     left join lower l
     on u.id=l.id

